# Azure Websites poodle vulnerability issue

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a website which is running on Microsoft Azure and enabled SSL for this website. After the poodle vulnerability issue, I just checked my domain on https://www.poodlescan.com/ and found that the domain is vulnerable.

On Microsoft Azure, there is no option to access the server and we can push the files only using git or FTP or something like that.

So my question is, is there any option to fix this issue? Or does Azure need to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

<del>You need to disable SSL 3.0. Take a look here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/19/how-to-disable-ssl-3-0-in-azure-websites-roles-and-virtual-machines/</del>

UPDATE: Microsoft disabled SSL 3.0 for Azure Web sites in December 2014, which solves the problem. http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/12/09/azure-security-ssl-3-0-update/

> SSL 3.0 has been disabled across Azure Websites. This no longer requires customer configuration changes.

Comment: This is one of the many articles ([alternative one for web roles and VMs](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/the-poodle-ssl-vulnerability-disabling-ssl-v3-in-your-azure-virtual-machines-and-web-roles/)) describing reasonable workarounds but I would argue that even in the short term this issue should be resolved/mitigated by Microsoft.

Comment: Completely agree, Microsoft needs to fix this urgently. Manually disabling SSL 3.0 is only a short-term solution.

Comment: Suppose I do disable SSL 3.0 What are the chances that users notice and come complaining?

Comment: Generally it will only affect IE6 users. More information: http://serverfault.com/a/637756